# One-of-a-kind objects

Tags: java

I want to create a one-of-a-kind object for certain properties:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SourceLanguage {
    private  final String name;
    private static HashMap<String,SourceLanguage> existing;

    private SourceLanguage(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public static SourceLanguage get(String name){
        if(existing==null){
            existing = new HashMap<>();
            SourceLanguage sl = new SourceLanguage(name);
            existing.put(name.toLowerCase(),sl);
            return sl;
        }
        SourceLanguage check = existing.get(name);
        if(check==null){
            SourceLanguage sl = new SourceLanguage(name);
            existing.put(name.toLowerCase(),sl);
            return sl;
        }else {
            return check;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use objects of this class as keys in another map.

I feel it's a bit of an overkill.
Is there an easier way to achieve the goal?

Comment: That's a memory leak.  And, no.

Comment: Memory leak in Java? I thought we had GC for that? @SLaks

Comment: @11684: GC can't clean objects, if objects have eligible references, so memory leaks can't be avoided if your code is not good.

Comment: @11684 - Once created and stuffed into the `existing` map, the instance will never be let go. This is a good time to use a `SoftReference`.

Comment: Untill you exit the app. But is that a problem? Perhaps that is what the OP wants.

Comment: @11684 - All memory leaks disappear when you exit the app. That doesn't make them innocuous.

Comment: This is also non-thread-safe.

Comment: Memory leaks are in fact self-healing: they cause the app to end, cleaning themselves up.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - So...cure the disease by killing the patient? :)

Comment: @TedHopp: I meant that perhaps the OP wanted to store keep this hashmap untill the app stops.

Comment: @11684 - Of course, if OP needs to keep both things, then it's not a leak. But as a general approach, OP's design has the defect of forcing the app to keep everything until it exits, whether or not that is the intent.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thanks for learning me something! @TedHopp

Answer (score 2):

You could look into using the [Registry pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html). That way the behavior of the `SourceLanguage` object could be separate from the behavior enforcing its unique-ness. They could also get more complicated independent of each other; the Registry could deal with the memory leaks described in the comments without cluttering your `SourceLanguage` class.

Put both the `SourceLanguage` and Registry classes in the same package, but make the `SourceLanguage` class package-visibile (or give it a `protected` constructor) and then external components will not be able to instantiate `SourceLanguage` directly and will have to go through the Registry.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest you avoid strong references for your cache. You also need some synchronization if this is going to be thread-safe.

```
public class SourceLanguage {
    private final String name;
    private final static Map<String, SoftReference<SourceLanguage>> cache
        = new HashMap<String, SoftReference<SourceLanguage>>();

    private SourceLanguage(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public static SourceLanguage get(String name){
        final String key = name.toLowerCase();
        SourceLanguage lang = null;
        synchronized (cache) {
            SoftReference<SourceLanguage> ref = cache.get(key);
            if (ref != null) {
                lang = ref.get();
            }
            if (lang == null) {
                SourceLanguage sl = new SourceLanguage(name);
                cache.put(key, new SoftReference<SourceLanguage>(sl);
            }
        }
        return lang;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is not about caching, but about maintaning one-off instances, basically runtime constants. For example, they could be used in efficient code that compares by reference. Also, caches based on soft references have already proved themselves as quite a performance disaster.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - I agree that the question isn't about caching _per se_. However, the idea here (and in OP's post) is to implement one-off instances by using a cache with the names as keys. Call it a "dictionary" if "cache" rubs you the wrong way. I don't know what you are talking about with soft references being "a performance disaster". Can you provide a reference for this?

Comment: The problem with soft refs is that they are retained until the memory is full---and then you lose **all** your cache, all at once. This usually happens at the most inconvenient time of increased pressure on the app, the pressure that caused memory shortage in the first place. So the cache lays around at times of plenty, vanishing precisely when it would be needed the most.

Comment: [This may serve in the way of a reference.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01246/index.html) Quote: For applications that rely heavily on caching for performance, soft references may be too blunt an instrument

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Using hard references can only make that scenario worse. Using soft references at least delays the memory full problem (assuming lots of garbage SourceLanguage objects). One can always ameliorate this by using a ReferenceQueue and a separate thread that polls the queue, removing the corresponding map entry when the garbage collector queues the soft reference. Also, OP doesn't seem to be relying on the cache/dictionary for performance, but to implement correct singleton behavior; so I don't think Goetz's comment applies.

Comment: OP also seems to want one-off values, so cache eviction is not necessary and there is no memory-full problem to worry about. Yes, `ReferenceQueue` would pretty much be assumed in a solution like this. Finally I should add that, if this is about interning as I presume, weak refs may even be a better match. For example, that's how Clojure interns keywords and symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, I think you could do this.

```
public class SourceLanguage {
    private  final String name;
    private static HashMap<String,SourceLanguage> existing = new HashMap<String, SourceLanguage>();

    private SourceLanguage(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public static SourceLanguage get(String name){
        SourceLanguage ret = existing.get(name.toLowerCase());
        if(ret == null) {
            ret = new SourceLanguage(name);
            existing.put(name.toLowerCase(),ret);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting goes under the general concept of *interning*. In general it is prone to memory leaks, but I doubt that would be a concern in your case since there won't be *that* many languages.

My advice to make this thread-safe is to use the `ConcurrentHashMap`:

```
private static final ConcurrentMap<String, SourceLanguage> existing = 
  new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public static SourceLanguage get(String name) {
  name = name.toLowerCase();
  final SourceLanguage old = existing.get(name);
  if (old != null) return old;
  final SourceLanguage 
    created = new SourceLanguage(name),
    justPut = existing.putIfAbsent(name, created);
  return justPut != null? justPut : created;
}
```

Comment: And if `SourceLanguage` instances expand to be 5MB dictionaries, you still won't be concerned about memory leaks?

Comment: @TedHopp That is not a realistic scenario, and the counterexample is not very relevant---instance count and instance size are on equal footing when it comes to worrying about leaks. Either the total memory is high, or isn't. My guess for this specific case is that it isn't.

Comment: Sorry, but instance size is very relevant. I use something similar to my answer with dynamically loaded bitmap fonts on a mobile device (tight memory). Loading a font is an expensive operation, so I want to avoid it if possible. But the fonts are very large and I run into problems if there are more than half a dozen font instances in memory at once. At any one time, I'm only using two or three fonts, but I don't want to unnecessarily unload the unused ones in case they are needed next. SoftReference works nicely, because a half dozen SoftReference instances is a negligible memory hit.

Comment: Yes, of course instance size is relevant, but it is an irrelevant counterargument. We can safely assume that both of us understand that memory load = instance_size * instance_count.